# I fixed a bug by mistake and want to understand why

Tags: c, cs50

I am new to programming and currently taking the [CS50x](https://pll.harvard.edu/course/cs50-introduction-computer-science) course. I have recently come across PSET 4 - Filter (more), in which I had to write a program in C to perform some actions with BMP pictures.
Before I share the issue, I want to point out that I do follow the guidelines of academic honesty, and I solved the problem myself. It has been submitted and computed (and I won't be sharing the complete solution, just the **first few lines of each step**). That being said, I just wanted some help to understand why my change fixed my code, as I have spent days and couldn't come up with an explanation. I believe this is important for my learning process.

The challenge was to use Sobel operator to identify and filter edges inside an image. After making a copy of the image (so I would not create a domino effect on the pixels), I created a 2D array to store the kernels and initialized some variables:

```
double gxRed = 0, gxBlue = 0, gxGreen = 0;
double gyRed = 0, gyBlue = 0, gyGreen = 0;

int gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
int gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
```

Then I addressed edge cases by nullifying the values of Gx/y:

```
if (i - 1 < 0)
{
    gx[0][0] = 0, gx[0][1] = 0, gx[0][2] = 0;
    gy[0][0] = 0, gy[0][1] = 0, gy[0][2] = 0;
}
```

Following, I computed each color channel according to the kernels array:

```
gxRed += (imageCopy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * gx[0][0]) + (imageCopy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed * gx[0][1]) +
                     (imageCopy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * gx[0][2]);
gxRed += (imageCopy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed * gx[1][0]) + (imageCopy[i][j].rgbtRed * gx[1][1]) +
                     (imageCopy[i][j + 1].rgbtRed * gx[1][2]);
gxRed += (imageCopy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed * gx[2][0]) + (imageCopy[i + 1][j].rgbtRed * gx[2][1]) +
                     (imageCopy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed * gx[2][2]);
```

Calculated the magnitudes and applied to the original picture:

```
image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed)));
```

Considered the 255 range and applied corrections if any:

```
if (image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
{
    image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
}
```

Everything complied fine and the resulting images looked good, as I expected. While running the course check, though, there were some problems with the green channel, as below:

*testing with sample 3x3 image*
*first row: (0, 10, 25), (0, 10, 30), (40, 60, 80)*
*second row: (20, 30, 90), (30, 40, 100), (80, 70, 90)*
*third row: (20, 20, 40), (30, 10, 30), (50, 40, 10)*

*Expected Output:*
76 117 255
213 228 255
192 190 255
114 102 255
210 150 60
103 108 255
114 117 255
200 197 255
210 190 255

*Actual Output:*
76 117 66
213 228 140
192 190 66
114 102 6
210 150 60
103 108 39
114 117 66
200 197 129
210 190 66

As you can see, there was a specific issue with the green channel. My first instinct was, obviously, double check every part of the code responsible for dealing with green, but there was nothing! It was EXACTLY the same code for the other colors, not even a single space different apart from gx/yGreen and .rgbtGreen. Then I went to the edge cases, but again, how can the other channels work fine and only green be off? They are all handled by the same logic, and I made sure of that by defining an array for Gx and Gy. It seemed just impossible to me that only the green channel of the pixel was misbehaving. If there was a problem with the code, the whole RGB values should be off. Well, I could notice, though, that the problem happened when green was 255 in the expected output, even though I treated this case the same way I did for blue and red. After days of headaches and almost giving up (I had already submitted the -less version, so this was optional), I just created a temporary variable to store the computation of Gx/y before addressing the 255 range, as below:

```
int tempGreen = round(sqrt((gxGreen * gxGreen) + (gyGreen * gyGreen)));
int tempRed = round(sqrt((gxRed * gxRed) + (gyRed * gyRed)));
int tempBlue = round(sqrt((gxBlue * gxBlue) + (gyBlue * gyBlue)));

if (tempGreen > 255)
{
    tempGreen = 255;
}
if (tempRed > 255)
{
    tempRed = 255;
}
if (tempBlue > 255)
{
    tempBlue = 255;
}

image[i][j].rgbtGreen = tempGreen;
image[i][j].rgbtRed = tempRed;
image[i][j].rgbtBlue = tempBlue;
```

It is the same code, I just added the variable and the problem was fixed. I passed all checks. WHY? If this was the issue, shouldn't it be happening to blue and red as well? This has been hunting me, so I decided to share here. I apologize for the super long post, this was my first one, so any tips on how to better write here are also welcomed.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: "It is the same code, I just added the variable and the problem was fixed." No. It is not the same code. `tempGreen` is an `int` while `.rgbtGreen` is a `uint8_t`. (I know this because I have read lots of CS50 questions, but generally it's your responsibility to provide **all** required information. All definitions etc.) `image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255` can never be true because any value larger than `255` would overflow already when you assign it to that variable. You cannot prevent an overflow or a wrap around after it has already happened.

Comment: @Gerhardh your comment should be written as an answer

Comment: "_shouldn't it be happening to blue and red as well?_" Who knows? It's called "RGB", and most people would consider the last value of the trio to be `blue`... (In this problem, it'd be just as well to refer to "colour1", "colour2", and "colour3".)

Comment: @Gerhardh, I remind you that the tooltip for the _Add a comment_ link is: _Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements._ ___Avoid answering questions in comments.___ (Emphasis added by me.)

Comment: @Gerhardh, you are totally correct, that did not cross my mind. It makes sense now, thank you!

Comment: @Abra, yes, this is the one

Comment: @EricAnacleto Aside: Does `gxGreen, gyGreen, ..` always contain integer values?

Comment: Hi @chux-ReinstateMonica, I defined them as double so they could fit the computation of the Sorbel operation. The problem is that I was causing an overflow when trying to assign the result directly to the image array, as the array is of uint8_t type, as pointed by Gerhardh on the answer. I completely missed that.

Comment: You clearly don't need `double` to calculate your Sobel operator. Plain `int` type should be sufficient. Using floating point types for plain integer calculation add unnecessary computing overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is the same code, I just added the variable and the problem was fixed.

No. It is not the same code.

`tempGreen` is an `int`, while `.rgbtGreen` is a `uint8_t`.

(I know this because I have read lots of CS50 questions, but generally it's your responsibility to provide all required information. All definitions etc.)

As a result, `if (image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)` can never be true because any value larger than `255` would overflow already when you assign it to that variable.

You cannot prevent an overflow or a wrap around after it has already happened.

Your fixed code checks for larger values before they are chopped to fit into the `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 0):

"I passed all checks. WHY?"

The **easiest** first step is to enable all warnings.

A good compiler would warn about `image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255` always being false.

Save time - enable all warnings.